# Scaling tikzpicture with Babel spanish package

Tags: tikz-pgf, babel, scaling

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,shapes,arrows,positioning,chains}
\usepackage[spanish,activeacute]{babel}

\begin{document}

% Define block styles
\tikzset{
desicion/.style={
    diamond,
    draw,
    text width=3em,
    text badly centered,
    inner sep=0pt
},
block/.style={
    rectangle,
    draw,
    text width=10em,
    text centered,
    rounded corners
},
cloud/.style={
    draw,
    ellipse,
    minimum height=2em
},
descr/.style={
    fill=white,
    inner sep=2.5pt
},
connector/.style={
 -latex,
 font=\scriptsize
},
rectangle connector/.style={
    connector,
    to path={(\tikztostart) -- ++(#1,0pt) \tikztonodes |- (\tikztotarget) },
    pos=0.5
},
rectangle connector/.default=-2cm,
straight connector/.style={
    connector,
    to path=--(\tikztotarget) \tikztonodes
}
}
\scalebox{0.85}{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\shorthandoff{<>}
\matrix (m)[matrix of nodes, column  sep=2cm,row  sep=8mm, align=center, nodes={rectangle,draw, anchor=center}, ampersand replacement=\&]{
\node [block] {A. Campos [1;14]}; \& \\
\node [block] {B. Bineado [1;4]}; \& \\
\node [cloud] {call \texttt{analisis\_campo}}; \& \\
\node [block] {C. Modelos [1;2]}; \& \\
\node [block] {D. Extinción [1;31]}; \&  \node [block] {E. Fracción de binarias [1;2]}; \\
\node [cloud] {call \texttt{analisis\_modelo}}; \& \\
\node [cloud] {call \texttt{analisis\_final}}; \& \node [desicion] {\scriptsize{Fin E?}}; \\
\node [desicion] {\scriptsize{Fin D?}}; \& \\
\node [desicion] {\scriptsize{Fin C?}}; \& \\
\node [desicion] {\scriptsize{Fin B?}}; \& \\
\node [desicion] {\scriptsize{Fin A?}}; \& \\
\node [block] {FIN}; \& \\
 };
\path [>=latex,->] (m-1-1) edge (m-2-1);
\path [>=latex,->] (m-2-1) edge (m-3-1);
\path [>=latex,->] (m-3-1) edge (m-4-1);
\path [>=latex,->] (m-4-1) edge (m-5-1);
\path [>=latex,->,dashed] (m-5-1) edge node[auto] {\scriptsize{MODEL}} (m-5-2);
\draw [>=latex,->] (m-5-2) |- (m-6-1);
\path [>=latex,->] (m-5-1) edge (m-6-1);
\path [>=latex,->] (m-6-1) edge (m-7-1);
\path [>=latex,->,dashed] (m-7-1) edge node[auto] {\scriptsize{MODEL}} (m-7-2);
\path [>=latex,->] (m-7-1) edge (m-8-1);
\draw [rectangle connector=2.5cm] (m-7-2) to node[descr] {No} (m-5-2);
\draw [rectangle connector=-3cm] (m-8-1) to  node[descr] {No} (m-5-1);
\draw [rectangle connector=-4cm,] (m-9-1) to node[descr] {No} (m-4-1);
\draw [rectangle connector=-5cm] (m-10-1) to  node[descr] {No} (m-2-1);
\draw [rectangle connector=-6cm] (m-11-1) to node[descr] {No} (m-1-1);
\draw [connector] (m-7-2) |- node[descr, pos=0.25] {Sí} (m-8-1);
\draw [straight connector] (m-8-1) to node[descr] {Sí} (m-9-1);
\draw [straight connector] (m-9-1) to node[descr] {Sí} (m-10-1);
\draw [straight connector] (m-10-1) to node [descr] {Sí} (m-11-1);
\draw [straight connector] (m-11-1) to node [descr] {Sí} (m-12-1) ;
\label{modelos_flow}
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\end{document}
```

I want to scale the tikzpicture but haven't been able to do it. The problem apparently is between the `tikz` and `babel` packages.

I've tried a couple of things I read in other questions:

1. Using `\shorthandoff{<>}`. This is needed to compile even when `\scalebox` is not used, but won't do any good once I turn `\scalebox` on.
2. Replacing the `&` character with `ampersand replacement=\&`. This improved nothing.

If I disable the `babel` package, scaling works. The problem is I **can't** disable that package because I'm writing in Spanish.

Any ideas?

Comment: You have to put `\shorthandoff` outside of `\scalebox`

Comment: Well, that was quick and easy. Thanks @egreg!

Comment: But why use `scalebox` ? You get a fine picture with TikZ and then you modify the line width, the size of the fonts etc. You use `em` in your graph but finally why ? There are solution to avoid the use of `scalebox`! You can easily change some dimensions to avoid this.

Comment: @Altermundus because it's easier than changing one thing at a time. This way I just resize the whole thing and be done with it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `\shorthandoff{<>}` command must go outside the argument to `\scalebox` or it won't have any effect.

You can better use `\deactivatequoting` and `\activatequoting` afterwards:

```
\deactivatequoting
\scalebox{0.85}{...}
\activatequoting
```

or better yet, since you're using Unicode input, call

```
\usepackage[spanish,es-noshorthands]{babel}
```

which will disable all shorthands. Check the documentation for more information: there is an extensive paper by Javier Bezos available with `texdoc spanish`.

You might alternatively choose to say `\deactivatequoting` after `\begin{document}`, if you don't need the "quoting" feature the shorthands `<<` and `>>` provide.